# SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error.torn page It occurred during a read of page

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I get the underlying error when I run the following query. Can you please help?

MY QUERY:

```
insert into MyDatabaseName.dbo.BoxContents (BoxContentID, Deleted, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, AuthCode, BoxID, ItemID, VariantAID, VariantBID, VariantCID, SerialNo, LotNo, Amount, Amount2, Amount3, SpecialCode, IntCode, Transferred, TransferDate, Locked, LockedBy, InOut)
select BoxContentID, Deleted, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, AuthCode, BoxID, ItemID, VariantAID, VariantBID, VariantCID, SerialNo, LotNo, Amount, Amount2, Amount3, SpecialCode, IntCode, Transferred, TransferDate, Locked, LockedBy, InOut
from MyDatabaseName2.dbo.BoxContents
where not BoxContentID in (
        select BoxContentID
        from MyDatabaseName.dbo.BoxContents
        where CreatedDate > dateadd(day, - 19, GETDATE())
        )
    and CreatedDate > dateadd(day, - 19, GETDATE())
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: torn page It occurred during a read of page (1:15856129) in database ID 9 at offset 0x00001e3e402000 in file 'H:\KLON_DATA**my database name.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: As it's said you should check SQL Server Error Log and System Event Log for additional details

Comment: Where can I check the system log? Can you cause this error?

Comment: @DemirciMustafa: system logs means `eventvwr' and sql server error log

Answer (score 1):

You should run a DBCC checkdb command against your target database.  That error signifies that there may be an issue with page corruption in your database file.  Running the command should tell you what is corrupt.  You may get lucky and it will just be an index that can be dropped and recreated.

Please see this [MSDB article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) for syntax

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issues with your hard disk or this may be a one time error due to some unexpected issue with your hard disk..

Few steps you can take

1.run [ChkDsk](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2854570/check-disk-chkdsk-runs-when-you-start-windows-8-or-windows-7) to see ,if your hard disk is in good condition

2.Next as suggested,run Dbcc checkDB to see what are the errors

```
DBCC CHECKDB (yourdbname)
```

based on the errors and repair option suggested,you can take next steps.Here is a good link to start with

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql

to know more on checkDB,see below link

[checkdb from every angle](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/checkdb-from-every-angle/) by Paul Randal

Comment: The size of the database is 135 GB. The DBCC CHECKDB (MyDatabaName) command is now running. Will it take too long and what will be the end of this command?

Comment: you can see status of that in sys.dm_exec_requests,also it is good idea to run dbcc checkdb on a backup db

Comment: Thank you very much for learning about the situation. What I do not understand is what does this 'DBCC CHECKDB' command do?

Comment: DBCC results for 'Piconn_SNOWY_KLONDB_NEW'.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown): Page (1:15856025) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8905, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Extent (1:15856112) in database ID 9 is marked allocated in the GAM, but no SGAM or IAM has allocated it.
DBCC results for 'CurrentCompetents'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "CurrentCompetents".

Comment: please update your question with entire messages :@DemirciMustafa